# onHandleIntent - Internet connection not working when app is closed

Tags: android, intentservice, android-wallpaper

I am using the IntentService to change wallpaper in the background. It gets invoked on receiving of a push notification. Below code works fine if notification is received while the application is open. But does not work if the Application is closed/killed (by swiping it away with help of menu button)

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    //Toast.makeText(this, "Intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String imageUrl = intent.getExtras().getString("imageUrl");

    try {
        URL url;
        try {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                    .getInstance(this);


            url = new URL(
                    imageUrl);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url
                    .openConnection().getInputStream());
            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PushReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Works fine when the application is opened. When closed/killed, it isn't able to download the image at `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream())`

Below is the stack trace.

I am using Mi3 Xiaomi device (Not sure if this helps)

App has permissions for android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

```
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to sgsbirds.com/182.50.149.129 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
W/System.err:     at org.dycusa.sgs.wallpapers.IntentServiceManager.onHandleIntent(IntentServiceManager.java:111)
W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
W/System.err:   ... 16 more
```

Comment: Is this happening even if the device display is unlocked? There's an option on Android to disconnect if the device is locked.

Comment: What is your current setting for "Restrict background data" in System Settings -> Data usage?

Comment: Yes, it is happening even if the device display is unlocked. In fact even the crashlytics failed to send the log due to `java.net.ConnectException`

Comment: @MateuszHerych I am not able to find this setting "Restrict background data". However I can see the setting to allow apps to use data over wifi and data.

Comment: @MateuszHerych. Bang on. I found the setting "Restrict background data" and it was off. Let me check this now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

"Restrict background data" setting for the app was off. I turned it on and everything started working.

@MateuszHerych was bang on.

Comment: Glad to help! Enjoy.